# Delete N bytes from the end of an inputstream

Tags: java, byte, inputstream, httpurlconnection

My goal is to delete the content of a file from another file, I can access those files through a HttpURLConnection.

My idea is to get the content-length from the first file, let's call N this content-length. And delete from the second inputstream (file2) N bytes.

```
HttpURLConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();

String contentLength1 = connection1.getHeaderFields().get("Content-Length").get(0);
String contentLength2 = connection2.getHeaderFields().get("Content-Length").get(0);
InputStream is = connection2.getInputStream();
```

EDIT:

I found a way to do it, I wonder if there is a better way.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream into = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];

for (int n; 0 < (n = is.read(buf));) {
    into.write(buf, 0, n);
}
into.close();

byte[] data = into.toByteArray();
int length1 = Integer.parseInt(contentLength1);
int length2 = Integer.parseInt(contentLength2);
byte[] newData = new byte[length2-length1];

System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, newData.length);
ByteArrayInputStream newStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(newData);
```

Comment: Please tag your platform. Please also show what you've tried so far as the question is too broad as stated - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Yassine Are you coding in Java? That is the only popular language I know that has a `HttpURLConnection` class as part of the standard library. Please show the relevant code for us to help.

Comment: I edited my question to give more information about my problem

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your InputStream in a class that just reads upto the desired length.

```
class TruncatedInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final InputStream in;
    private final long maxLength;
    private long position;

    TruncatedInputStream(InputStream in, long maxLength) ... {
        this.in = in;
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    @Override
    int read() ... {
        if (position >= maxLength) {
            return -1;
        }
        int ch = in.read();
        if (ch != -1) {
            ++position;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Mind skip, reset. The usage of a BufferedInputStream is not inadvisable.

It is a bit more typing actually, but delivers a solid tool having just one single responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891920), but it doesn't work for me - specifically I can't see how the `read` method can return anything but -1.

I extended it with the following:

```
/**
 * Truncates a {@link java.io.InputStream} to a specified number of bytes. <br>
 * <br>
 * Based on <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891920">this implementation</a>. <br>
 * <br>
 * <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/52149547">Source</a>.
 */
public class TruncatedInputStream extends InputStream
{
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final long maxLengthInBytes;
    private long position;

    /** @see TruncatedInputStream */
    public TruncatedInputStream(final InputStream inputStream, final long maxLengthInBytes)
    {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.maxLengthInBytes = maxLengthInBytes;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException
    {
        return position++ < maxLengthInBytes ? inputStream.read() : -1;
    }
}
```

In addition, I wrote a unit test:

```
public class TruncatedInputStreamTest
{
    @Test
    public void testTruncatedInputStream() throws IOException
    {
        byte[] input = new byte[] {};
        doTest(input, new byte[] {}, 1);
        doTest(input, new byte[] {}, 0);

        input = new byte[] {0};
        doTest(input, new byte[] {0}, 1);
        doTest(input, new byte[] {}, 0);

        input = new byte[] {0, 1};
        doTest(input, new byte[] {0, 1}, 3);
        doTest(input, new byte[] {0, 1}, 2);
        doTest(input, new byte[] {0}, 1);
        doTest(input, new byte[] {}, 0);

        input = new byte[] {0, 1, 2};
        doTest(input, new byte[] {0, 1, 2}, 3);
        doTest(input, new byte[] {0, 1}, 2);
        doTest(input, new byte[] {0}, 1);
        doTest(input, new byte[] {}, 0);
    }

    private void doTest(final byte[] input, final byte[] expectedOutput, final long length) throws IOException
    {
        try (PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(); InputStream truncatedInputStream = new TruncatedInputStream(pipedInputStream, length))
        {
            try (OutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInputStream))
            {
                IOUtils.write(input, outputStream);
            }

            final byte[] actualOutput = IOUtils.toByteArray(truncatedInputStream);

            assertArrayEquals(Arrays.toString(actualOutput), expectedOutput, actualOutput);
        }
    }
}
```